# Create Time Table using JavaScript at the developer console

Tags: javascript

I am learning JavaScript and I want to make times table from 2 to 10 and want to display it at the developer console. I could only do the times table of 2. But I could not do it up to 10.

My code is :

```
var i = 0;
var j = 2;
var product = i*j;

for (i=0; i<=10; i++) {
  console.log(j,"*",i,"=",product);
}
```

I wrote this code and could make it only for the times table of two. What can I add to it to make the times table up to 10 and display it at the developer console? The time table must be displayed vertically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `var product = i*j;` here is constant. You should put this inside the *For Loop*:

```
var i = 0;
var j = 2;


for (i=0; i<=10; i++) {
  var product = i*j;
  console.log(j,"*",i,"=",product);
}
```

---

**Edit:** You are still using ES5 syntax. It is fine but since today is already 2020, I recommend you to learn modern JavaScript ES6 (aka ES2015) and beyond. I think ES6 is cleaner and makes a lot of things easier. Here's your code example from ES5 to ES6:

```
const j = 2;

for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  console.log(`${j} * ${i} = ${j * i}`);
}
```

**Helpful Links:** [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let), [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const), [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Indeed, learning ES5 first is still relevant because it is still valid for ES6+ and won't give you a headache by often searching ES5 syntax that you don't understand when working on legacy codes.

Comment: nice catch! simple and interesting :)

Comment: Actually, I am just learning javascrip.  So, I want to make this using  only this. As I am learning and I am just a beginner, I will learn the others later. Now I want to make times table upto  10.

Comment: for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j <= 11; j++) {
 // your code here
}

@AzmainKhan, here's my hint. There are many solutions from the internet but please at least try. Give this a shot. :)

Comment: Thank you very much bro, it worked. Though have to modify your code a little, but thank you, because you gave me the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You also can use `console.table` if you desire:

```js
const j = 2;
const table = [];
for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    table.push({i,j,product:i*j});
}
console.table(table)
```

Comment: But how can I make the times table upto 10.